# Sonarqube integration with Gitlab

Tags: php, sonarqube, gitlab

I am pretty new to Development community and specifically to DevOps practices , as a part of PHP project we are trying to integrate SonarQube with Gitlab , did some R& D on SonarQube and Git CI ( Continuous Integration ) and look like plugin is released for Github and SonarQube whereas not for Gitlab.

How realistic is it to configure GitLab with SonarQube for inspecting code quality for every commit and what will be the best practice to integrate these two piece.

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin

Answer (score 0):

It's very realistic - I'm doing that :) Check out my description in other thread and feel free to ask any questions if you have problems: [Run sonarqube scanner with gitlab ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875287/run-sonarqube-scanner-with-gitlab-ci/40612088#40612088)